# how to avoid adding principal in glassfish-web.xml file?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, web-applications, glassfish, jaas

I have a small web application that use jdbcRealm for authentification/authorisation.
The authorisation works only if I put the user name in the glassfish-web.xml

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <class-loader delegate="true"/>
    <jsp-config>
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
            <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
        </property>
    </jsp-config>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>connexion</role-name>
        <principal-name>test</principal-name>
        <group-name>connexion</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

web.xml

```
<!--other stuff-->
     <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/Downloader</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>/start.html</url-pattern>  
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>connexion</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
            <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <login-config>
            <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
            <realm-name>my_realm</realm-name>
            <form-login-config>
                <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
                <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
            </form-login-config>
        </login-config>

        <security-role>

            <role-name>connexion</role-name>
        </security-role>
<!--other stuff-->
```

If I remove the principal from the glassfish-web I get a 403 error acces denied .
Is there any solution to avoid adding principals in xml file ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. In your security realm (from the content of web.xml, that is `my_realm`) associate the username you are logging in with the appropriate group - in your case that is `connexion`. In other words, every user that belongs to the group `connexion` will have the access to the protected resource and therefore you don't have to enumerate the principals - that's the purpose of groups.

Reference & further reading: [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html)